# Replace multilines file every time a certain string occurs in another file with powershell, batch or Notepad++

Tags: powershell

I have a file with about 50 thousand different lines of text that needs to be placed into another file (with 500 thousand lines) every time this string occurs:

```
[2]
 1 string data = "
```

This string is followed by an English text and ends with **"** and must be replaced with an Italian text that I take from the 50 thousand line file.

Example
File of 500 thousand lines (**code.txt**):

```
other lines of code
[1]
other lines of code
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "first spanish text"
    [2]
     1 string data = "first english text"
other lines of code that have japanese and chinese characters.
[2]
other lines of code        
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "another text in spanish"
    [2]
     1 string data = "here is another text in English"
other lines of code that have japanese and chinese characters.
```

File of 50 thousand lines (**ita.txt**):

```
first text in Italian
another text in Italian
one again
```

Merged Output (**codeita.txt**):

```
other lines of code
[1]
other lines of code
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "first spanish text"
    [2]
     1 string data = "first text in Italian"
other lines of code that have japanese and chinese characters.
[2]
other lines of code        
    [0]
     1 string data = ""
    [1]
     1 string data = "another text in spanish"
    [2]
     1 string data = "another text in Italian"
other lines of code that have japanese and chinese characters.
```

I have tried this code, but it does not paste all the strings correctly, because in the files there are strings with double " at the start and at the end (1 string data = ""some text" and other") and have the character **'**
When they occur, they are skipped, leaving the English text in place and bringing the text that was supposed to be there to the next line.
Furthermore, the characters are encoded incorrectly, making accented letters, Japanese, Korean etc. illegible.

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader] (Convert-Path ita.txt)

# Read code.txt as a whole
# and perform regex-based replacements of the parts
# of interest, iteratively using ita.txt's lines as replacement text.
[regex]::Replace(
  (Get-Content -Raw code.txt),
  '(?<=\[2\][^=]+?= ")[^"]+',
  { $reader.ReadLine() }
) | 
  Set-Content -NoNewLine codeita.txt  # Save to the output file.

$reader.Dispose() # Close and dispose of the reader.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
$reader = [IO.StreamReader] (Convert-Path ita.txt)

[regex]::Replace(
  (Get-Content -Raw -Encoding utf8 code.txt),
  '(?<=\[2\][^=]+?         1 string data = ").*(?=")',
  { $reader.ReadLine() }
) | 
  Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding utf8 codeita1.txt  # Save to the output file.

$reader.Dispose() # Close and dispose of the reader.
```

- With -Encoding utf8 the problem of accents and Asian characters is solved
- With .*(?=") I indicate all content up to the last " excluded.

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.